# Spring boot thymeleaf direction to id user

Tags: html, spring, jsp, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Could you please help me with one issue.
I want go to current user by id but I don't know how write it by thymeleaf.
In jsp I have wrote:

```
<c:forEach items="${users}" var="user">
<a href="/user-${user.id}">${user.username}</a><br>
</c:forEach>
```

By thymeleaf I tried do it in this way:

```
<th:block th:each="user:${users}">
<a th:href="@{/user}"><p th:text="${user.username}"></p></a>
</th:block>
```

Please help with this issue.
Maybe this is not a reasonable question, but it would be great if you help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding of the question you asked, you want to create a link with your `user_id` linked with it. For that you can try this :--

```
<th:block th:each="user:${users}">
     <a th:href="@{user(id=${user.id})}"><p th:text="${user.username}"></p></a>
</th:block>
```

On your controller would be like this :--

```
    @RequestMapping("/user")
    public String editCategory(@RequestParam("id") String userId){

            //your code

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work. It will redirect the user to the following url /user/id.

```
<th:block th:each="user:${users}">
    <a th:href="'/user/'+${user.id}"><p th:text="${user.username}"></p></a>
</th:block>
```

Your controller will now be receiving a variable path. So it will end up looking like this.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}")
public String getUser(@PathVariable("id") String userId) {
    // Do something!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need the `th:block`.  You can simply put the `th:each` directly on the `<a />` tag.  Second, you can use the [Thymeleaf `@` syntax](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#link-urls) for generating urls.  Here is what your converted code should look like:

```
<a th:each="user: ${users}" th:href="@{/user-{id}(id=${user.id})}" th:text="${user.username}" />
```